# Профилирование в Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, профилирование

1. Как найти наиболее вызываемые функции в конкретном потоке? 
   Когда делаю профилирование, то собираются функции со всех потоков. Хотелось бы расставить метки чтобы анализировалась только 1 функция и все что из неё вызывались. Убрать все данные от других потоков и сторонних библиотек.
2. То есть у меня в приложении работает несколько потоков. Но мне нужно проанализировать только 1 мою крупную функцию которая вызывается 1 раз, и во время этого вызова найти медленные участки именно в ней и нигде больше.
3. Инфы в инете конкретной нет, только общие пространные рассуждения на эту тему.

Comment: Вообще, профайлер от MS может выдавать информацию о строках и даже отдельных инструкциях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ. 
Профилирование собирает все вызовы функций отовсюду. 
Проще всего отфильтровать те, что не проходят по условию.
Для этого нужно сделать так же как и на картинке.
Запустить профилирование, а **уже после окончания и вывода результатов** применить фильтр по конкретному потоку(потокам) или процессу. 
Тогда можно будет просмотреть все функции конкретного потока и отфильтровать по наибольшему количеству вызовов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]